# Pip==6.0.6 not finding previous package versions, yet Pip==1.5.6 does

Tags: python, pip, versions

Specifically, when trying to install Jinja2==2.6 with pip v6.0.6 (within virtualenv), I get this error

```
(venv) $ pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 6.0.6
Location: path..
Requires: 

(venv) $ pip install Jinja2==2.6
Collecting Jinja2==2.6
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jinja2==2.6 (from versions: 2.7.3)
No distributions matching the version for Jinja2==2.6
```

Yet when I use pip v1.5.6 (system pip - /usr/local/bin/pip), it finds and installs the package just fine. Why is that?

```
(venv) $ /usr/local/bin/pip install Jinja2==2.6
...success
```

pip 6.0.6 also produces the same error when trying to install any previous version of ANY package.

Comment: If it's installed with another version of `pip`, then what is the problem?

Comment: Because it should still work with the current version of pip and I'd like to know why it's not.

Comment: @user3004175 tried it on Mac OS X, python 2.7.6, pip 6.0.6 - works for me, no errors.

Comment: I could not reproduce with `pip 6.0.6` and `python 2.7.3` on Mac OS X either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had previously changed my pip.conf file to search for packages in a private location. Still not sure why this didn't raise errors with pip 1.5.6 though.